# No matter what I query, MySQLWorkbench gives me the same response

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

While I am just learning MySQL and MySQLWorkbench, and have perhaps have done something boneheaded, I cannot find a reference to this.

Suddenly, no matter what line of code or what query I run, it outputs the same response even if I query for tables disconnected to the response. The database tests connected. I have run the use command. I have tried to google hack this and found nothing close to my situation. It was running just fine. I did not change the database. I was just running some very basic SELECT queries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your installation ?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I’m fairly new to the software. What should I check?

Comment: If everything works normal beside that. Also try to reinstall